# PostgreSQL json formatting

Tags: postgresql

I'm frequently running a SQL query where I simply get two items back, like uid and name, and then in my PHP code I turn that into a JSON object where the key is the UID and the value is the name.  Is there a way to just have PostgreSQL return that JSON already formatted like that?  The only thing I can find would be getting back an array of objects, with the actual keys as 'uid' and 'name'.

So my SQL query might return this:

| ** UID ** | ** Name ** |
|-----------|------------|
| ABC       | Sally      |
| DEF       | BOB        |

And for output I'd want:

{
      "ABC" : "Sally",
      "DEF" : "BOB"
    }

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with t (key, value) as ( values
    ('abc', 'john'),
    ('def', 'mary')
)
select json_object(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
from t
;
           json_object            
----------------------------------
 {"abc" : "john", "def" : "mary"}
```

Comment: Could you give a more specific example please where you get those array values from the SQL query instead of hardcoded?

Comment: @Gargoyle From the table columns. Edited

Comment: So very close.  That's returning as many objects as there are rows, with one key and one value.  I want to get back just one object, with as many key/value pairs as there are rows.  I updated my question to show more specifically what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Gargoyle Updated

Comment: You are a rock star.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As From PostgreSQL 9.2, it support JSON format. It includes a JSON data type and two JSON functions. These allow us to return JSON directly from the database. sample below,

> row_to_json() function

Use like  `select row_to_json(words) from words;`
will return

> {"id":6013,"text":"advancement","pronunciation":"advancement",...}

You can implement it in you case.

Comment: This is what I said I don't want though.  I don't want the keys to be the column headers.  I want the key to be the UID and the value to be the name.

Comment: well, ok , got it wrong in first place , this might help , https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/set-names-to-attributes-when-creating-json-with-row-to-json